# Analysis of the reduction of a function using (outermost) graph-reduction

Tags: asymptotics, runtime-analysis, functional-programming, evaluation-strategies

I want to determine the time and space complexity of the following functions:

```
subs [] = [[]]
subs (x:xs) = subs xs ++ map (x:) (subs xs)

subs' [] = [[]]
subs' (x:xs) = yss ++ map (x:) yss where yss = subs xs
```

The language I'm considering is using (outermost) graph-reduction (also known as call-by-need or call-by-name + sharing). Knowing that would it be correct to assert the following?

1. both definitions have the same reduction graph
2. their time complexity is $O(n^2)$
3. their space complexity is $O(2^n)$

Thanks!

Comment: If you're not printing the result (or forcing its evaluation in some other way), everything is $O(1)$. If you do print, then you can just compute the call-by-value complexity because by printing, you force everything to get fully evaluated and the only thing that will change is the order in which things are computed (which doesn't matter for complexity).

Comment: If you give lists with no repeating element as input, in a way, you're computing all subsets. So when given a list of size $n$ your functions will return lists of length $l(n)=2^n$, and the (unshared) total size $s(n)$ of the list (i.e. the length of all the list it contains, concatenated) will be $\Theta(n2^{n-1})$ (see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610110/total-size-of-all-subsets-of-a-set-is-n-cdot2n-1)). Given that, you could try to write the recurrence relations to compute the complexities.

Comment: @xavierm02 thanks for catching the error in the space complexity, a typo from transcribing my notes, I updated the question. And yes I didn't make it explicit but the evaluation is somehow forced, thanks for pointing that out.